# populating the select box with options

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am trying to populate the select box with options but it is not populating the select. I am getting the json from the ajax call. I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is my attempt:

```
$.getJSON('checkpictures.cfm?mode=getitem&itemID='+itemname, function(result) {
        var $select = $("#associated_order");
        $select.html('');
        //don't forget error handling!
        $.each(result, function(items) {
        $select.append($("<option />").val(items.orderID).text(items.orderunique));
        }); 
    });
```

my JSON object

```
[{"itemid":1,"orderid":3,"orderunique":"RXGRFBD9","itemname":"Imperial"},{"itemid":1,"orderid":7,"orderunique":"ARN82Z3M","itemname":"Imperial"}]
```

Also, I am missing error handling here, how can I add it. Please guide, thanks

I am using a chosen2 plugin, so here is the generated html for this, it is populating the select box but not the custom plgin:

```
<div class="controls">
    <select data-rel="chosen" data-placeholder="Please choose one" id="associated_order" class="passitem" style="width: 200px; display: block;" name="associated_order"><option value="">29ZDBKZ7</option><option value="">T69AEJZV</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 200px;" title="" id="associated_order_chosen"><a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single chosen-default"><span>Please choose one</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"></ul></div></div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
$.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'checkpictures.cfm?mode=forqty',
            data: data, 
            success: function(result) {
                    $("#qtymsg").html(result);
                    if($hostname.indexOf('sell') > -1){
                        $.getJSON('checkpictures.cfm?mode=getitem&itemID='+itemname, function(result) {
                        $select.html('');
                        //don't forget error handling!
                        $.each(result, function(i,items) {
                            $select.append($("<option />").val(items.orderID).text(items.orderunique));
                          });   
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $select.trigger("liszt:updated");
```

it is still not populating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback for [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes two arguments. The first is the index, or key; the second is the value.

```
$.each(result, function(i, items) {
    $select.append($("<option />").val(items.orderID).text(items.orderunique));
});
```

Comment: ok, so here i think i am close to the issue, i am using a custom select named as `chosen`. With that it is not populating the select, any idea. the chosen link: [link]http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/[link]. I am editing  myquestion to add a chosen2 style

Comment: Are you initializing chosen on the `<select>` after it's populated?

Comment: @soft_spo Then you need to do it after it's populated.

Comment: can you elaborate it with an example

Comment: By now it already seems like a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)